# What formula will work in Google Sheets to split and extract data from one cell to multiple cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have cells with 4 pieces of information in each cell.
Each piece of information has a label.

I'm trying to extract the 4 pieces of information (without the labels) into the next 4 cells.

Results I'm Looking for:
Columns E-H to list the corresponding data (pulled from Column D), without the Labels (Calendar:, Start Time:, End Time:, Details:)

EXAMPLE:

COLUMN D

```
|Calendar: 02/08/2019, Start Time: 12:00 PM, End Time: 10:00 PM, Details: Birthday|
```

Should break into COLUMN E - H as

```
| 02/08/2019 | 12:00 PM | 10:00 PM | Birthday|
```

Comment: Welcome. On this site code should be included as text, not as image. Besides that, the question looks to be too broad. Please checkout [ask].

Comment: Rubén - Thank you for the feedback. I will re-evaluate.

Comment: Regarding the last edit, solutions should be posted as answers. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution, it is ugly and long - but it works!

```
=SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D9,"Calendar: ","^"),", Start Time: ","^"),", End Time: ","^"),", Details: ","^"),"^",TRUE,TRUE)
```